# Is it possible to use planet scale load-balanced virtulisation?

Tags: load-balancing, storage-area-network, hypervisor, fault-tolerance, dynamic-routing

there are more and more implementations of distributed-virtualisation. A common one is Microsoft [SCVMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Virtual_Machine_Manager).

Currently, such things are kept inside LANs, and a san or fiber-channel system is used for fault-tolerance *(It often store VM's RAM with realtime update)*. Given that a part of the data need very high band-width network storage, I'm aware it would require a special and high-cost contract with the ISP.

The point of my question is :  Given that there is some part of [allocation by range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry), is it possible for virtual machines running inside a such infrastructure to get an accessible public IP address?
If yes, would it be also possible with IPV6?

Comment: I think you're confused about what SCVMM is.  It is VM management, not distributed virtualization.  Distributed virtualization... Well, isn't actually a thing, any more than distributed commuting or distributed eating is.  Distributed virtualization, as it actually exists today is about allowing access to shared resources by distributed VMs, not about distributing a virtualized machine.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork : Yes SCVMM is VM management. It is also part of the Microsoft way to do fault-tolerance and load-balancing *(at the virtual machine instance level)* between several Hyper-V hosts.

Comment: Neither of which is "distributed virtualization."  Fault tolerance is fault tolerance and load-balancing is load balancing.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).  If that doesn't answer your question, I'm stumped at what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @yoonix : I think that public IPs may partially routed using region addressing.  IPV6 address allocate address subnets according to the the location on the earth. Here, the VM may be dynamically relocated to an another workstation located in an another continent and still keep the same IP.

Comment: VTC silly and confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some fundamental gaps in your understanding of how virtual machines work:

- Distributed virtualisation? What? SCVMM/vSphere are not distributed virtualistion, they are just virtualisation managers.
- Your comments about FC are irrelevant to your actual question?
- Yes, virtual machines can and often do get non RFC-1918 IP addresses that are routable on the internet.
- Apart from link-local addresses, there's not really any such thing as a non-routable IPv6 IP address. So yes, of course it can get a routable IPv6 address

Comment: "Yes, virtual machines can and often do get non RFC-1918 IP addresses that are routable on the Internet." : My concern is weather their address will remain routable (In the case of an address everyone can reach) if the hosts which run the hypervisors are located on several continents in the world. *(I already know you can host a web server in virtual machine in a single LAN network)*

Comment: I think the phrase you are looking for is "anycast". but I think you have some serious misunderstandings about how virtualisation works. You can't just migrate a VM from one side of the world to the other without some seriously expensive infrastructure.

Comment: `I'm aware it would require a special and exapnsive contract...` That's what's I was saying.